what really happens when an electron pair is shared in a bond?
I've never been able to understand how bonding between two atoms works.

When two atoms share an electron pair, does it mean the valence electrons of both atoms stop revolving in their shells and stop somewhere between the two atoms?
I have also never understood what an ionic bond is, because if an atom donates one of its electrons to another atom, how could there be a bond holding them together? since both the atoms have done so to attain stability, they wouldn't be charged or unstable, to still be attracted to each other.


Why the downvotes? Is my question too elementary for this website?? I don't understand what mistake I have made.


Electrons do not actually revolve, though they do have angular momentum. That is an oddity of quantum mechanics.
Electrons don't exist at a point, though when observed they appear at a point. Think of them as a wave, with the amplitude of the wave being the likelihood of finding (observing) the electron in a place. Imagine a cotton ball, fluffed out at the edges and hollow at the center, with greatest density about 0.1 nm (~1 Å) from the center. Yep, another quantum quirk.


In the diagram above, adapted from from R. Bader, Atoms in Molecules,

On the average electrons in the first diagram, covalent chlorine, $\ce{Cl2}$, can be found with equal probability around around either nucleus.

On the average, an outer electron in the second diagram, ionic sodium chloride, $\ce{NaCl}$, is more likely to be found around the chlorine atom (well, ion), effectively giving it partial negative charge. It is less likely to be found around the sodium atom (yes, ion, if you prefer), giving it a partial positive charge.
Now, like a balloon that has an electrostatic charge, they cling to each other.


So in a crystal lattice, a cube of table salt, static electricity holds things together... and not all that tightly; it's easy to cleave a salt crystal with a sharp blade. However, unless solvated, those electrons and ions don't roam. Dissolved in water, though, "Things fall apart; the centre cannot hold; Mere anarchy is loosed upon the world," as Yeats put it.

Nitpick: They have the property of angular momentum, but its magnitude might be zero. Also, they have kinetic energy and are trapped so they must be "revolving", just not like classical particles.

@BuckThorn, yes, and they even have near-relativistic velocity for inner shells of transuranics... yet they can go from one side of a barrier to the other, without going through it, as in the readily-available Esaki/tunnel diode, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode. The less kinetic energy, the less determined is the position. Curiouser and curiouser. See also https://poets.org/poem/antigonish-i-met-man-who-wasnt-there

Schrodingers-cat-in-the-hat-in-the-box?


When two atoms share an electron pair, does it mean the valence electrons of both atoms stop revolving in their shells and stop somewhere between the two atoms?

Electrons in an individual atom move around in 3D spaces called orbitals. These orbitals have different shapes, orientations, and energies, and each orbital can only hold two electrons. When two atoms come together and share their valence electrons, the half-filled orbitals of these valence electrons overlap and form a new orbital with a different shape but lower energy (more stability). This new orbital surrounds both atoms, and the bonding pair of electrons is shared between them. If both atoms have almost equal electronegativity, then this electron pair will surround both atoms equally, as in the case of Cl2. If one atom is more electronegative than the other, there will be unequal sharing of the electron pair, which will spend more time closer to the more electronegative atom, as in the case of HCl. Lastly, if the electronegativity difference between the two bonded atoms is very large, there will be a transfer of electrons instead of sharing, leading to an ionic bond, as in the case of NaCl.


I have also never understood what an ionic bond is, because if an atom donates one of its electrons to another atom, how could there be a bond holding them together? since both the atoms have done so to attain stability, they wouldn't be charged or unstable, to still be attracted to each other.

As I mentioned earlier, when the electronegativity difference between two atoms is very large, one atom attracts the electron of the other atom so strongly that this electron leaves the nuclear hold of the other atom and "gets attached" to the more electronegative atom. This results in the formation of two ions. In NaCl, chlorine is highly electronegative compared to sodium. Therefore, there is a complete transfer of electron, and both chlorine and sodium achieve stability by gaining the electronic configuration of their nearest noble gas. Now, even though they have achieved stability, these atoms (now called ions) are oppositely charged. Chlorine, having gained an extra electron, becomes a negative anion. Sodium, having lost an electron, becomes a positive cation. Due to electrostatic attraction between these oppositely charged ions, they come close and form a chemical bond called an ionic bond.
In your question, you made a mistake by calling these ions "uncharged." A neutral atom, when there is no loss or gain of electrons, is "uncharged." Even though there are charges inside the atom in the form of negative electrons and positive protons, they are equal in number, resulting in no net charge on the atom. However, when an atom gains an electron, this balance of charges is lost, and the atom gains a negative charge. Conversely, when a neutral atom loses an electron, it loses a negative charge, resulting in a net positive charge on the atom. This was a fundamental mistake in your thinking. Ions can be stable, but they will always be charged.
